# Padding plaintext blocks in TwoFish

Tags: encryption

When using encryption with TwoFish it is inevitable that at one time or another you will run into a situation where the last plain text block is less than 128 bits. How is padding handled in that case? For example say the last block is only 112 bits (14 bytes). Would you just fill byte 15 with random bits and use the 16th byte to tell how much padding is contained in the block? In this case being the last byte could contain 00010000 to indicate that 16 bits of the block are padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different [padding mechanisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) that are in common use today; which one is chosen is mostly a matter of the protocol designer picking one and saying it is the standard for that protocol. (I don't know of any compelling reasons to pick one over the others.)

The most-common one I know of, and works to allow sub-byte (bit-level) padding is to add a single `1` bit followed by as many `0` bits are necessary to finish the block.

The next-most-common one I know is to pad with zeros or random data and use the last byte in the block to indicate how many bytes were used for padding.

You can also use as a byte value however many bytes you need to use for padding; pad with `0x01` if you need to add one byte, `0x04 0x04 0x04 0x04` if you need to pad four bytes, etc.

One little trick that might catch you up is that you almost always need to add a padding block -- even if the entire block is padding -- just so you have a reversible transformation. If you neglect to add a padding block when the message is a multiple of the block size, you might try to strip off legitimate message contents as padding. You can either signal the lack of padding through some other mechanism or you can always add the padding. (Which is often easier.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the very detailed response. I'd give you more than one up vote if I could.